# Highcharts Y-axis title text length is more than chart's height

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, highcharts

I am working on highcharts. In my code, sometimes Y-axis title text is more than chart's height.

Ex. I am create one chart. In this chart, height is `400px` but my Y-axis title text is long so some part of the text is not display. so what can i do?

[see in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EUSVQ/10/)

Comment: If it's that long I'm not sure it's going to look very elegant in any case, but how about either having line breaks in the title, or simply setting `style.fontSize` to something smaller?

Comment: You can add height and width to the class `.highcharts-yaxis-title` and set `overflow:hidden` and add title attribute to display tooltip over it

Answer (score 0):

You can set width on title and adapt margin.

```
yAxis: {
        title: {
            enabled: true,
            text: 'Custom with <b>simple</b> <i>markup</i>Custom with <b>simple</b> <i>markup</i>Custom with <b>simple</b> <i>markup</i>Custom with <b>simple</b> <i>markup</i>',
            margin: 40,
            style: {
                width: 200,
                fontWeight: 'normal'
            }
        }
    },
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/EUSVQ/12/