# highcharts y-axis title wrap

Tags: highcharts, freemarker, word-wrap, yaxis

I have a chart with varying heights based on a parameter, due to which the y-axis title gets cut off at the top when height becomes less than the title length.

The highchart api at http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.title specifies a style property where CSS styles for the title can be given, but the javascript wordWrap:'break-word' isn't working here.

My question is - Is there any property that can wrap the title of the the y-axis in such a case ?

Note: I searched SO and found a question - [Highcharts Y-axis title text length is more than chart's height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29918054/highcharts-y-axis-title-text-length-is-more-than-charts-height), but this doesn't answer my case as I don't have a static title and cannot have a 
 tag to force the line break.

Comment: can you post the image

Comment: Please post code snippet which you tried, word-wrapping works in highcharts

Comment: Here is the fiddle demoing the problem : http://jsfiddle.net/mxyvnb8v/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add fixed width and step in the style:

```
    title: {
                enabled: true,
                text: 'very long title text here that will get cut off at the top when height becomes less than the length of the title',
                style: { 
                    font: 'bold 10pt "Arial Narrow"',                       
                    color: 'rgb(0,0,0)',
                    wordWrap:'break-word',
      // Add these        
                    width : "200px"
                }
            }
```

your [Fiddle updated here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/mxyvnb8v/6/)

Comment: Nishith, using fixed width forced the title to wrap, yes, thanks ! Now the title will still be wrapped for greater chart height value also which should not be. So I will have to calc this width dynamically based on the chart height. Additionally, specify an offset value, also dynamically calculated, so that wrapped title doesn't overlap the labels.
What does "step:1," do precisely ?

Comment: Yes, that's for label actually and shouldn't be there in title's style. Plz remove that, Step is used in yZxis labels when you have lot of label and you want to skip after a step interval.

Comment: Finally I added the width calculated based on chart height as:

events: {
 load: function() {
    this.yAxis[0].setTitle({ 
   style: {
     width: this.chartHeight - 100
   }
    });
 }
}
in the chart's load event

Comment: Great !! appropriate way